# Unable to import module in Google Colab after installing

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

I was trying to clone and install the Google Unrestricted adversarial examples repository following the instructions provided [here](https://github.com/google/unrestricted-adversarial-examples/blob/master/warmup.md). But I am unable to import the any of the modules. First I cloned the repository and changed to that directory.

```
!git clone https://github.com/google/unrestricted-adversarial-examples.git
cd unrestricted-adversarial-examples
```

Then I used the pip install command.

```
!pip -e install bird-or-bicycle
```

The installation completed without any error. However, when I try to import I get the 'module not found error'. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I tried the same commands on my PC and it works.

```
import bird_or_bicycle
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bird_or_bicycle'

Answer (score 7):

I just got the solution after posting an [issue](https://github.com/google/unrestricted-adversarial-examples/issues/42) to the repository. The solution was simple, all I needed to do was restart the Colab kernel (Restart Runtime option in the Runtime tab) after `!pip -e install bird-or-bicycle` Apparently that is required to pick up the newly installed package.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [bird-or-bicycle docs](https://github.com/google/unrestricted-adversarial-examples/tree/master/bird-or-bicycle), you see that there is a data download step required after you pip install.

If you follow the instructions there and run the following in a notebook cell, then the import will work:

```
!git clone https://github.com/google/unrestricted-adversarial-examples
!pip install -e unrestricted-adversarial-examples/bird-or-bicycle
!bird-or-bicycle-download
```